# XML creates element name from XSD ComplexType, not from Element name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a XSD schema generated into C# code using SVCUTIL.exe. Then I'm filling the generated code with data and returning it as reponse in WCF service.

In the generated xml response, in one of my elements, the element name is the name of the complex type, not the element name in XSD.
Example:

```
  <xs:complexType name="ReadSchoolsResponseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Schools" type="SchoolsType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="SchoolsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="School" type="SchoolType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

and the generated XML is:

```
<ReadSchoolsResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Schools>
    <SchoolType> </SchoolType>
  </Schools>
</ReadSchoolsResponse
```

Why did the School element render as SchoolType? I have a lot of elements created the same way and it serializes correctly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the solution:
Deleting the SchoolsType complex type name and move the element details in.

```
  <xs:complexType name="SchoolsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="School" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="asdf" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="qwer" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="yxcv" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="tzui" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

However I still have no idea why the code in question doesn't work.